XAML Template for Popup
I am new to C# Maui and stuck on a simple task where I could not find any information how to do it.
My goal is to create a XAML-Template, which I then can fill with other XAML-Content.
My Idea is to have something like this as a new template
<HorizontalStackLayout x:Class="MyTemplate">
    <Label Text="template header" />
    <!--new content here-->
    <Label Text="template footer" />
</HorizontalStackLayout>

So afterwards I use it like this:
<MyTemplate>
    <Label Text="content" />
</MyTemplate>

Which then should create the same output as:
<HorizontalStackLayout>
    <Label Text="template header" />
    <Label Text="content" />
    <Label Text="template footer" />
</HorizontalStackLayout>

Obivously I do not want to add just a label but as much stuff as I want. In my case I want to use it amongst others to create a template for an pages which all should have the same stuff above and below.
I tried it like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mct:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
             x:Class="Page.EntryPopup">
    <ContentView>
        <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <Label 
                        Text="Header"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                    <ContentPresenter />
                    <Label 
                        Text="Footer"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView>
</mct:Popup>

And afterwards:
<page:EntryPopup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
             xmlns:page="clr-namespace:View.Page"
             x:Class="Page.ActivityPopup">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</page:EntryPopup>

But this showed only "Welcome to .NET MAUI!" but not the header and footer.

Do you mean  a Popup page with a header and footer by using ControlTemplate?

Shen's answer is the correct one for you question, hands down. However, you might want to check how some custom control work for presenting content. Here is the code for expander: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui/Views/Expander/Expander.shared.cs At some point you will want to write some "code behind".

ControlTemplate should apply to the Popup that you want to use. You can define the customized ControlTemplate in Resources, and just consume it in the Popup,
You may define the ControlTemplate in Application Level and give it a x:Key attribute for the Popup to reference it,
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        ...
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="Header"/>
                <ContentPresenter />
                <Label Text="Footer"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

And consume it in the Popup,
<mct:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        ...
        >

    <ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}">
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Label 
                Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>          
    </ContentView>
</mct:Popup>

For more info, please refer to Control templates and Resource dictionaries.

Yes, that obviously works but because in this case the template does not inherit mct:Popup and I cannot use the stuff used defined in Popup.
But I use it like this for now, probably look for a better solution later.

Do you mean inherit a XAML? That's not how it works. Even though you do it like this case Is there any way to inherit Xaml in dotnet Maui, you have to write more extra code in code behind.
